# Linearizing the Kullback-Leibler Divergence

Tags: derivatives, probability-distributions, linearization

The [Kullback_Leibler Divergence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kullback%E2%80%93Leibler_divergence) is a measure of how one distribution differs from another.

For distributions $P$ and $Q$ of a continuous random variable, the K-L divergence is
$$D_{KL}(P||Q) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}p(x) \log\left(\frac{p(x)}{q(x)}  \right)dx, $$
where $p(x)$ and $q(x)$ are the probability densities of $P$ and $Q$, respectively.

I am trying to obtain a linearized version of the K-L Divergence, where the distribution $Q$ is fixed and treating $D_{KL}$ as a function of $P$; call this function $D_{KL}(P)$. I wish to then linearize this around $P=Q$.

From the standard formula, the linearization would take the form
$$L_{D_{KL}}(P) = D_{KL}(Q) + \frac{dD_{KL}}{dP}(Q)[P-Q]. $$

Obviously the first term is $D_{KL}(Q)=0$, but I am not sure how to deal with the derivative term or if the normal linearization works in this case.

Comment: what is $L_{D_{KL}}$?

Comment: I just used that as my own notation for the Linearized form of $D_{KL}$ defined above.

Comment: I need to doublecheck, but my recollection is that the linear term goes away, and that you get a second-order term which is $\chi^2$. Maybe I'm misinterpreting your question, though: see, eg., Theorem 6 in http://people.lids.mit.edu/yp/homepage/data/LN_fdiv_short.pdf

Comment: Thanks for the reference. From a quick reading it does seem that the linearization I want would be trivial. I will need to read it more carefully to see how they got that result.
I do specifically need something linear in $P$ so I might need to use a different comparison.

Comment: @ZackStevens In the case of KL, you can write, linearizing the logarithm (I'm ignoring conveniently the higher-order terms)

$$\begin{align*}
\int_{\mathbb{R}}p(x)\log \frac{p(x)}{q(x)}\, dx
&=\int_{\mathbb{R}}p(x)\log\left(1+\frac{p(x)-q(x)}{q(x)}\right)\, dx\\
&\approx \int_{\mathbb{R}}p(x)\left(\frac{p(x)-q(x)}{q(x)}\right)\, dx\\
&=\int_{\mathbb{R}}\frac{p(x)^2}{q(x)}\, dx - 1
\end{align*}$$
(the last equality as $\int_{\mathbb{R}} p(x)\,dx = 1$)

Comment: This happens to be the $\chi^2$ divergence:
$$\begin{align*}
\int_{\mathbb{R}}\frac{(p(x)-q(x))^2}{q(x)}\, dx
&= \int_{\mathbb{R}}\frac{p(x)^2}{q(x)}\, dx - 2\int_{\mathbb{R}}p(x)\, dx
+ \int_{\mathbb{R}}q(x)\, dx
= \int_{\mathbb{R}}\frac{p(x)^2}{q(x)}\, dx - 2+1 \\&= \int_{\mathbb{R}}\frac{p(x)^2}{q(x)}\, dx - 1
\end{align*}$$